# Should all tests be nested under the "integration" folder? (Best practice)

Tags: cypress

My company is giving Cypress a try and, right now there is a project with two main folders where all tests are placed under: the default "integration" and "Smoke".

Is that the right tests organisation? Shouldn't be better to place all tests under "integration" and then give them there our structure? What are the best practices to follow here? I wasn't able to find an answer to this in the documentation.

Comment: I keep mine under integration. I would say you should do what is best for your org.. At the end of the day can I find the test easily.. This is more of an opinion related question so I did not leave an answer..

Comment: we use subfolders within `integrations` to group tests by a more technical perspective (e.g. all specs of one module go into `integration/module1/`)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. One of our developers created that isolated "Smoke" folder to place a bunch of tests to be run regularly once or twice per week at night. My guess is that perhaps it would be better to put it also under "integration" and create a specific config file to run those tests.